# What do I need for Castle Windsor's "DefaultInterface"?

Tags: dependency-injection, repository, castle-windsor

I found this code:

```
public class RepositoriesInstaller : IWindsorInstaller
{
   public void Install(IWindsorContainer container, IConfigurationStore store)
   {
      container.Register(AllTypes.FromAssemblyNamed("Acme.Crm.Data")
                            .Where(type => type.Name.EndsWith("Repository"))
                            .WithService.DefaultInterface()
                            .Configure(c => c.LifeStyle.PerWebRequest));
   }
}
```

...[here in the official docs](http://docs.castleproject.org/Windsor.Installers.ashx)

...and modified it to:

```
public class RepositoriesInstaller : IWindsorInstaller
{
    public void Install(IWindsorContainer container, IConfigurationStore store)
    {
        container.Register(Classes.FromThisAssembly()  
                                  //AllTypes.FromAssemblyNamed("Acme.Crm.Data")
                                  .Where(type => type.Name.EndsWith("Repository"))
                                  .WithService.DefaultInterface()
                                  .Configure(c => c.LifeStyle.PerWebRequest));
    }
}
```

...but "DefaultInterface()" is not recognized or currently resolvable.

I added "using Castle.MicroKernel.Lifestyle;" because that had [bit me before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20768044/why-is-castlewindsors-beginscope-out-of-scope) but no joy in Mudville.

What using statement do I need to illuminate/discover/resolve "DefaultInterface"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There seems to be a typo in the official docs. I think you need to put 'DefaultInterfaces' rather than 'DefaultInterface'.

```
public class RepositoriesInstaller : IWindsorInstaller
{
    public void Install(IWindsorContainer container, IConfigurationStore store)
    {
        container.Register(Classes.FromThisAssembly()  
                              //AllTypes.FromAssemblyNamed("Acme.Crm.Data")
                              .Where(type => type.Name.EndsWith("Repository"))
                              .WithService.DefaultInterfaces()
                              .Configure(c => c.LifeStyle.PerWebRequest));
    }
}
```